# Remapping Random Float value to logarithmic scale

Tags: function, random, logarithm

I have a Random float that gives me a value between 0 and 1.
I now want to remap that value so that 50% of the time the result is 0.01, 25% of the time it't 0.02, 12.5% of the time it's 0.04....

Somewhat like this:

- 50%      = 0.01
- 25%      = 0.02
- 12.5%    = 0.04
- 6.25%    = 0.08
- 3.125%   = 0.16
- 1.5625%  = 0.32
- 0.78125% = 0.64

Or with other words remapping 0.0 - 0.5 to 0.00 - 0.01 and 0.50 - 0.75 to 0.01 - 0.02...

I think I can do that with a logarithmic function but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `x`, a number in the interval (0, 1), the formula you want is `2^floor(-ln(x)/ln(2)) * 0.01`.

- `t = -ln(x)/ln(2)` - Negative base-2 logarithm of `x`.
- `u = 2^floor( t )` - Round `t` and raise 2 to it.
- `u * 0.01` - Multiply by 0.01.

Example in Python:

```
import math
arr=[2**int(  (-math.log(random.random())) / math.log(2) ) * 0.01 for i in range(1000)]
print(arr)
print(sum(1 if u==0.01 else 0 for u in arr)/len(arr))
```

There is another way to proceed. Let `x` be your number again.

```
base=0.01
v=x # Original number
if base!=0:
   while v<0.5:
      base*=2
      v*=2
print(base) # Mapped number
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I'm not sure about how you worded the second last line there but I'm assuming the function you're writing is mapping [0,1.0] st. 0.05 -> 0.01, 0.25 -> 0.02 right?

If I'm following then 0 -> 0.1 and 1.0 -> -0.11.

Plotting that out looks pretty cubic to me, not logarithmic. It's been a while but I think there's a formula by Lagrange that you can use to interpolate the function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Hope that's helpful!